# Azure s2s VPN connection with dynamic public IP

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

We are creating s2s vpn between on prem and Azure. We have VPN appliance on prem with public facing IP which is dynamic. Will it work or I need
Static IP?

Comment: Hi Manu, from the questions you are asking take a look to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) if it would not be the better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work and you only need a public facing IP address and it shouldn't be NAT. Dynamic or static IP address usually is different from the IP assignment method. When you deploy an S2S VPN connection, you will create a virtual network gateway and a local network gateway.

> The local network gateway typically refers to your on-premises
>   location. You give the site a name by which Azure can refer to it,
>   then **specify the IP address** of the on-premises VPN device to which
>   you will create a connection.

For more references, you may want to know [Site-to-Site connections and VPN devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#s2s).

Step-By-Step: [Configuring a site-to-site VPN Gateway between Azure and On-Premise](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2017/06/28/step-by-step-configuring-a-site-to-site-vpn-gateway-between-azure-and-on-premise/)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly do refer [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181181/Azure-Local-Network-Gateway-Dynamic-IP-Update) ,
You can do this with a dynamic IP, but needs a bit of tweaking.

Answer (score -1):

You need a static IP from on-prem firewall or router.

Referance - [Azure VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal)